# Como gravar campos com acentuação em sqlite3 via Python?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Oi, pessoal! Estou fazendo um pequeno programa em python e utilizando sqlite3 pra guardar a base de dados. O programa está inserindo, lendo e deletando dados na banco de dados chamado "posicao". Gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de exibir dados acentuados quando os leio no console (terminal). Veja a imagem:

[image: No id 19 - A palavra introdução está codificada.]

```
#JavaScript
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os, sys
import sqlite3

def Inserir():
    ###INSERINDO
# solicitando os dados ao usuário
p_nome = raw_input('Nome: ')
titulo_unicode = p_nome.decode('utf8')
p_criado_em = raw_input('Criado em (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
print (titulo_unicode)

# inserindo dados na tabela
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO posicao (nome, criado_em)
VALUES (?,?)
""", (titulo_unicode, p_criado_em))

conn.commit()
def Ler():
    ###LENDO
    # lendo os dados
    cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM posicao;
    """)

    for linha in cursor.fetchall():
        print(linha)

def Excluir():
    id_posicao = int(raw_input('Digite a posicao: '))

    # excluindo um registro da tabela
    cursor.execute("""
    DELETE FROM posicao
    WHERE id = ?
    """, (id_posicao,))

    conn.commit()

    print('Registro excluido com sucesso.')


conn = sqlite3.connect('posicao.db')
#conn.text_factory = str
cursor = conn.cursor()
opcao = 1
while opcao!=4 and opcao!=0:
    print ('Menu:')
    print ('1 - Inserir dados: ')
    print ('2 - Ler dados: ')
    print ('3 - Deletar dados: ')
    print ('0 ou 4 - Sair!!!')
    opcao = int(raw_input('Opção: '))
    if opcao == 1:
        Inserir()
    if opcao == 2:
        Ler()
    if opcao == 3:
        Excluir()

conn.close()
```

Como fazer para quando ler o banco as palavras acentuadas não apareçam codificadas?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver! Coloquei o código para imprimir cada coluna da tupla separadamente.

```
def Ler():
    ###LENDO
    # lendo os dados
    cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM posicao;
    """)

    for linha in cursor.fetchall():
        print "|\t",(linha)[0],"\t|",(linha)[1],"\t|", (linha)[2]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]